# Linux kernel does not boot when Intel integrated graphics is enabled

Tags: linux, boot, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, dual-gpu

I have a Desktop PC with an Intel H87 chipset (Intel DH878RL board, in case that matters), a CPU with integrated graphics and a dedicated NVidia GeForce 560Ti. Both are connected to the same display, because I only ever want to use one of them at a time. Please note that my monitor automatically switches inputs if the current input doesn't have a signal.

My system is using Grub2 in UEFI mode. I want to use the Intel integrated graphics for Linux, but have to keep the NVidia card as the primary because Windows does not properly disable the Intel GPU before I log in (see [Windows: Use Intel Onboard GPU for bootup, then switch to NVidia](https://superuser.com/questions/831811/windows-use-intel-onboard-gpu-for-bootup-then-switch-to-nvidia)).

Windows boots fine, regardless of how th graphics cards are configured in UEFI setup. However, **Linux fails to boot if both GPUs are enabled and the NVidia is set as the primary GPU**.

### Different configurations I tried

- Primary GPU: Intel;
  Kernel: Intel driver compiled in
  *Boots OK*
- Primary GPU: Intel;
  Kernel: Both Nouveau and Intel compiled in
  *Boots OK, using Intel driver*
- Primary GPU: NVidia, integrated graphics disabled
  Kernel: Nouveau driver compiled in
  *Boots up OK*
- Primary GPU: NVidia, integrated graphics disabled
  Kernel: Intel and Nouveau drivers compiled in
  *Boots up OK, using Nouveau driver*
- Primary GPU: NVidia, integrated graphics disabled
  Kernel: *No graphics drivers nor framebufer drivers selected*
  *Boots up OK*, does of course not display anything but allows me to connect via SSH and reboot via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>
- Primary GPU: NVidia, integrated graphics enabled
  Kernel: Nouveau driver compiled in
  **Does not boot**, showing no message at all.
- Primary GPU: NVidia, integrated graphics enabled
  Kernel: Intel and Nouveau drivers compiled in
  **Does not boot**, showing no message at all.
- Primary GPU: NVidia, integrated graphics enabled
  Kernel: *No graphics drivers nor framebufer drivers selected*
  **Does not boot**

How can I make the kernel boot (***Bonus question***: and use the Intel GPU) when the NVidia card is set as primary and the Intel GPU is enabled?

**Please note:** I know that I can use the Nouveau drivers, but I would prefer not to, because they exhibit severe performance issues, even in 2D mode. Setting the Intel GPU as primary is also not an option, unless someone can answer [Windows: Use Intel Onboard GPU for bootup, then switch to NVidia](https://superuser.com/questions/831811/windows-use-intel-onboard-gpu-for-bootup-then-switch-to-nvidia).

Comment: Use Intel Onboard GPU for bootup, then switch to NVidia